# alpha(transparency) is replaced w/ black - why?

Tags: php, image

I've tried two different images and still get the alpha/transparency replaced by black:

The original code used `imagejpeg` which I've commented out b.c. jpegs do not support transparency and replaced by `imagepng`.

Here are my original test images that contains alpha:

[image]

[image]

Here is the solution I tested from php.net.  Actually this distorts black and white images /w alpha background.

```
private function imageCreateTransparent($x, $y) {
    $imageOut = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
    $colourBlack = imagecolorallocate($imageOut, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($imageOut, $colourBlack);
    return $imageOut;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some attempts, it turns out that using imagefill *does* work with alpha, but you need to call `imagesavealpha` as well.

The final code will look like this if you wrap it in a function.

```
function imagecreatealpha($width, $height)
{
    // Create a new image
    $i = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    // for when you convert to a file

    imagealphablending($i, true);
    imagesavealpha($i, true);

    // Fill it with transparent color (translucent black in this case)
    imagefill($i, 0, 0, 0xff000000);

    return $i;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$i = imagecreatealpha(500, 500);

// Further processing goes here

// Output
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($i);
```

The same applies to loading png images with alpha transparency in it. Oddly enough PHP doesn't do this automatically:

Comment: I removed the old clutter. The current code is tested and works and could be used instead of the `imageCreateTransparent` method that is in your question. Also cleaned up my comments regarding the old attempt.

Comment: I thought you were creating a new, blank, image on which you would draw a loaded image and/or other things?

Comment: I've added a piece for loaded png images. Turns out you also need to call `imagesavealpha` there as well. Maybe `imagealphablending` too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `imagesavealpha` and `imagealphablending` functions.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php first example.

Comment: It's just an extra function that needs to be called before `imagepng`. Look at the example!

Comment: Because I'm lazy - and look, you learned something that you won't forget in the future ;)

Comment: after much troubleshooting...those methods are not needed...they add in "alpha channels"...you can have one color alpha which is all I need...it is working now w/ out those methods.